# Pass an array of objects from model to JSP using Spring and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am facing a problem with JSP and Spring, I am trying to pass array of objects from the model to the view (JSP).

This is my code in the controller part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clientes.html")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("arrClients", this.clientManager.getClients());
    myModel.put("clientNames", this.clientManager.getNames());
    return new ModelAndView("clients", "model", myModel);
}
```

In the JSP file I have access to "arrClients" using jstl, i.g:

```
    <c:forEach items="${model.arrClients}" var="client">
        <div id="newClient">
            <p>
                <c:out value="${client.name}" />
                <i><c:out value="${client.surname}" /></i>
            </p>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

This code is working, but I'd like to access to this array in the , to store it in a jQuery var.

There if I try to access to the other array (Strings), it's works and I have the message in the console.

```
$(function() {
    var clientNames = ${model.clientsNames};
            console.info('it Works!!');

}
```

But when I try to access to the other array

```
$(function() {
    var clients = ${model.arrClients};
            console.info('it Works!!');
}
```

I can not access to this array, I could not even get the console message. 
Does anyone know how can I access to an array of Objects in a JSP file using jQuery?

Comment: you can't. you will need to build a javascript array from java array.

Comment: You can create JSON string from your list in Java code and then deserialize it into JavaScript Object with `jQuery.parseJSON('${model.arrClients}')`. `model.clientsNames` works probably because it's a list of primitives, which has `toString()` representation as valid JavaScript array like ["one", "two", "three"].

Comment: @Xaerxess this actually worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that the JSP output is interpreted in the JS as if you were typing it yourself. Therefore your line:

```
var clients = ${model.arrClients};
```

would be OK if the contents of `${model.arrClients}` was `["foo", "bar"]` but would not be OK of it was something like `foo, bar`. Use the Javascript debugging tool (Firebug, Chrome console, etc) to look at the console error log and also look at the actual HTML output in your page at that line.

The fact that the second `console.info()` is not appearing, suggests your JSTL expression has caused a JS syntax error.

Edit: as gigadot pointed out you can't take a Java Object like a List or array and declare it in the JSP - you will simply get the `toString()` representation, which will usually not be what you want. You'll need to do use similar code with a `<c:forEach>` block and add each element to your JS array, one at a time (e.g. with `.push()`).

Comment: I haven't tested it but I think you can get away with: `var clients = ["${fn:join(model.arrClients, '","')}"];` (note: assumes a String[] array).

Comment: Thank you so much all of you!! I am going to try